# Android - streaming sensor data continuously?

Tags: java, android, networking

I have the following code giving me some sensor data:

```
private void computeOrientation() {
        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null, m_lastAccels, m_lastMagFields)) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(m_rotationMatrix, m_orientation);

            /* 1 radian = 57.2957795 degrees */
            /*
             * [0] : yaw, rotation around z axis [1] : pitch, rotation around x
             * axis [2] : roll, rotation around y axis
             */
            float yaw = m_orientation[0] * 57.2957795f;
            float pitch = m_orientation[1] * 57.2957795f;
            float roll = m_orientation[2] * 57.2957795f;

            /* append returns an average of the last 10 values */
            m_lastYaw = m_filters[0].append(yaw);
            m_lastPitch = m_filters[1].append(pitch);
            m_lastRoll = m_filters[2].append(roll);

            yawText.setText("azi z: " + m_lastYaw);
            pitchText.setText("pitch x: " + m_lastPitch);
            rollText.setText("roll y: " + m_lastRoll);

                    //Now I want to send those 3 values over the network
                    //whenever they're calculated
}
```

This function will be invoked every few milliseconds I reckon, from `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`.

I want to continually send/stream this data over internet network to a remote device, that will be using the data stream to calculate things in real time.

How should I do this? Through sockets? An AsyncTask? Example source code for getting started would be much appreciated =)

Comment: I also have same issue, I'm reading data from 3 sensors over WIFI , but data stream get stop for few second sometime, while it work good (get continuous data stream without any delay) when we enable the AIRPLANE mode on android.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a Service to calculate the data in background. Because no UI is necessary you can use a Thread insteed of an AsyncTask to get the sensor data.

There is more detail needed in general, but especially for the setup of the connection between your phone and the remote device. If you use a LAN, sockets in combination with a ByteArrayriter on the Phone and a ByteArrayReader on the device should do the job.

Comment: So let the service calculate the data in the background, ok, then from within the service send over a socket? Would that work?

Comment: 1) issues running network requests on the UI thread, and 2) speed of transfer; though I will try this out as it's the only way. In terms of setup, I was thinking the main thread could do the calculations and the service could simply be the socket communication - does that make sense? Or do everything in the service?

Comment: You can do all in your service: get the sensor data and the network connection. Just be sure to use a Thread, how I said before. And don't break your head on the performance of the data transfer if you dont have any requirements below 1-2ms.

Comment: Sounds good, though I don't understand re: using a thread within a service? I thought a service basically functioned as a background thread, so I could do both the sensor calculations and socket communication over it.

Comment: The docs are very clear about [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)

Comment: You're right I just saw. I will try with an AsyncTask and report back.

Comment: Hey, here is my attempt and current problems if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798521/android-socket-doesnt-connect-to-laptop-server-but-local-java-program-can

Comment: Not Useful, Problem is from cell signal, when airplane mode enabled android get able to read high speed data from wifi, but stucked when on normal mode