# Android Socket doesn't connect to laptop server - but local Java program can

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, networking

Networking being a pain. In a service using AsyncTasks I attempt to start socket communication:

```
public class TransmitService extends Service {

    private Socket echoSocket = null;
    private static PrintWriter out = null;
    private String HOST = null;
    private int PORT = -1;
    private static Context context;
    public static boolean isConnected = false;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO do something useful
        context = getApplicationContext();
        HOST = intent.getExtras().getString("HOST");
        PORT = intent.getExtras().getInt("PORT");
        Toast.makeText(context, "HOST/PORT: "+HOST+"/"+PORT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new initNetworkTask().execute();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    // Send the orientation data
    public static void sendData(float f1, float f2, float f3) {
        new sendDataTask().execute(f1, f2, f3);
    }

    static class sendDataTask extends AsyncTask<Float, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Float... params) {
            try {
                JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                j.put("yaw", params[0]);
                j.put("pitch", params[1]);
                j.put("roll", params[2]);
                String jString = j.toString();
                out.println(jString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("sendDataTask", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    class initNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                echoSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
                out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("Welcome.");
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("initNetworkTask", e.toString());
                isConnected = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

My "server" is just a python script running on my laptop:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.###.#'     #(numbers omitted from S/O question)             
PORT = 10000             
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data is not None:
        print data
conn.close()
```

The following server works just fine with this Java client running on the same laptop:

```
public class DataSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        //BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.###.#", 10000);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;

        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput); //out.println - THIS IS HOW DATA IS SENT
            //System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }

        out.close();
        //in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I really want to get this to work in my Android app - my purpose is to continuously stream orientation data via `TransmitService.sendData(f1,f2,f3)` to my laptop.

In terms of testing: I have turned off windows firewall, I have tested on the same WiFi connection (Starbucks) and tried a few other ports (80, 4444, 4445, 5000).

The comment error I get in my Android app is:

`java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.###.# (port 10000): connection failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

Thanks for taking a look, would be happy to provide more information / run more tests to get this issue resolved. I'm also interested in considering other solutions for sending the orientation data from phone to laptop over internet.

Comment: Do you have internet hosting? If you could drop it onto a box in the clouds and try that, it might provide some insight (and probably better logging over a Windows laptop!!)

Comment: No, in fact my application is meant to be phone-to-laptop wireless communication. Though if you know any alternatives for that I could do with Android, I'd be interested.

Comment: just found it funny that you omitted a private IP from us :D

Comment: @Fred this is probably indicative of my lack of experience with anything network-related. This one time my friend said he stole my IP address, I asked him to "give it back"...

Comment: You're using private (non-routable) IP addresses; your phone has to be on the same private network as the laptop. That error is telling your phone can't make a connection to the specified IP address because there's no route / no device with that IP on the same local network

Comment: Is there a way I can get my phone on the same local network as my laptop, or vise-versa? What's the solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy this is silly and embarrassing. Basically I was using the wrong IP address (192.168....).

In Windows, use ipconfig (Linux: ifconfig), and choose the IP address corresponding to Wireless LAN (wlan). I was using another IP address corresponding to a virtual machine or some crap.

Hope this helps someone else in the future, I hate these kind of issues.